# Issue with creating legend if min and max value supplied are not in between 0 and 1

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend, scale, continuous

I have created continuous legend using scale Linear in d3js and it works fine. But I also have scenario where min and max value are not in between 0 and 1 but have value [2315, 4516].
So I am passing min as 2315 and max as 4516 to my legend. Also mine dataset for point and color varies in between 0 and 1 as shown below

My Data:

```
[
[0.0, 255, 0, 0],
[0.2, 255, 255, 0],
[0.4, 0, 255, 0],
[0.6, 0, 255, 255],
[0.8, 0, 0, 255],
[1.0, 255, 0, 255]
]
```

where 0.0, 0.2,0.4 and so on is the value/point and rest are rgb values for the point.

If I give my domain values in between 0 and 1 it works fine but if I change domain value beyond that it shows only 1 color. I want my min and max(in my case 2315 and 4516) to map into 0 and 1.

I have share the fiddle link for more clarification where I have changed the domain to 2315 and 4516(works fine if I set it to 0 and 1)

Code Snippet:

```
item Color = [{
offset: 0.0,
color: "#ff0000"
},
{
offset: 0.2,
color: "#ffff00"
},
{
offset: 0.4,
color: "#00ff00"
},
{
offset: 0.6,
color: "#00ffff"
},
{
offset: 0.8,
color: "#0000ff"
},
{
offset: 1.0,
color: "#ff00ff"
}
];

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const colorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([2315, 4516]).range([0, 400]);
const id = "linear-gradient-0";
const linearGradient = svg.append("defs")
.append("linearGradient")
.attr("id", id)
.attr("x1", "0%")
.attr("x2", "100%")
.attr("y1", "0%")
.attr("y2", "0%");

// append the color
linearGradient
.selectAll("stop")
.data(itemColor)
.enter()
.append("stop")
.attr("offset", function(data) {
return colorScale(data.offset) / 4 + "%";
})
.attr("stop-color", function(data) {
return data.color;
});

// draw the rectangle and fill with gradient
svg.append("rect")
.attr("x", 10)
.attr("y", 18)
.attr("width", 400)
.attr("height", 20)
.style("fill", "url(#linear-gradient-0)");

// create tick
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(10,45)").call(d3.axisBottom(colorScale));
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7Ludyrsf/1/

Comment: `return colorScale2(2315 + (data.offset * (4516 - 2315))) / 4 + "%";` ??

Comment: Thanks @RobinMackenzie it seems to be working . Can you explain me the above written calculation ?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I am asking this question because I am not so good with this d3. Does it make sense to only change the ticks and keep the legend same for both linear and logarithm ? I mean for the legend, to keep the colors the same as for the linear interpolation and only change the axis ticks. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/51xqf3L7/ . Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: the calc I put in the comment fixes that when  `offset` 0-1 goes into the `colorScale` with domain 2315-4516 you getting super limited colors - so I can see that you are using domain  max - domain min now which looks generic solution.